# What is unclear about my question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[This question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/707587/124071) was just closed as unclear. I haven't really received any feedback as to what people find unclear. One user said they didn't understand the question and suggested to rework the title, but that's not really much for me to go off.

Of course this is totally fair. It is very common to know you don't understand something, but to not be able to explain why. Noone owes me that explanation.

So I am taking what I view as the next step, and asking a broader audience.  How do I clarify my question?

Comment: When people vote to close they have to choose from a limited number of options so likely 'unclear' was just the closest. I don't know, but I suspect your question was closed because it is a do-it-for-me rather than focusing on a particular problem you encountered when trying to use `dynkin-diagrams`, for example. Personally, I would have left a comment initially rather than voting immediately to close. On the other hand, you're not new to the site, so people probably think you've been asked to include a minimal working example before.

Comment: @cfr I'm used to adding an MWE when there's an error or when something behaves unexpectedly. What would a MWE look like for this? Would it be including other diagrams I have drawn with the library? Or is it something not code like explaining why I think this diagram might not be possible with the library?

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic You could include the closest looking diagram you can manage, e.g. something tune-fork-shaped shouldn't be too hard. This would on the one hand show people that your question isn't just the usual do-it-for-me and on the other hand also give people willing to help you a starting point so that they don't have to do all the boring stuff like adding a document class.

Comment: Code for some part of the diagram or the closest you can manage with some explanation, if possible, about why you're not sure how to continue or modify it to match the target.

Comment: I've added an example group. Looking at the result, it's my opinion this sort of buries the question. I just want to know from someone who knows the package whether this is something it's built to make or whether I'm using the wrong tool, but I'll leave it since I'm not likely to get an answer any way.

Comment: @cfr: Can you write up an answer for this?